# Server memory to process xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, dml

I'm calling my stored procedure about 2.500 that work with xml file stored in the column using the functions (this function are xquery):

*exist, modify, value*

My code:

```
    IF(@Data.exist('(Incumbent/Data[1]//*[local-name() = sql:variable("@ColumnName")])') = 0)
        BEGIN               

            -- Set new command to property.
            SET @New_Nodes_Cmd = 'SET @Data.modify(''insert <' + @ColumnName + '/> as last into (/Incumbent/Data)[1]'')';               

            EXECUTE sp_executesql @New_Nodes_Cmd, N'@Data [xml] OUTPUT', @Data = @Data OUTPUT;

        END;

        SET @New_Cursor_Column_Values_Cmd = N'SELECT @ColumnValue = CAST([' + @ColumnName + N'] AS [nvarchar](1024)) FROM ' + @Table + N' 
                                                WHERE [RowId] =' + CAST(@RowId AS [nvarchar](32)) + N';';

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @New_Cursor_Column_Values_Cmd, N'@ColumnValue [nvarchar](1024) OUTPUT', @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue OUTPUT;

        SELECT @XmlValue = (SELECT @ColumnValue FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE);    

        SET @IsThere_Node_Value_Cmd = N'SET @IsThereNodeValue = @Data.exist(''(Incumbent/Data[1]/' + @ColumnName + N'[1]/Value)'');'    

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @IsThere_Node_Value_Cmd, N'@IsThereNodeValue [bit] OUTPUT, @Data [xml]', @IsThereNodeValue = @IsThereNodeValue OUTPUT, @Data = @Data;

        IF(@IsThereNodeValue = 0)                       
            BEGIN                       

                SET @NewNode = '<Value Date="' + CONVERT([nvarchar](64),GETDATE(),20) + N'">' + CAST(@XmlValue AS [nvarchar](1024)) + N'</Value>';                                              

                SET @New_Nodes_Cmd = N'SET @Data.modify(''insert sql:variable("@NewNode") as last into (/Incumbent/Data/' + @ColumnName + N')[1]'')';                       

                EXECUTE sp_executesql @New_Nodes_Cmd, N'@Data [xml] OUTPUT, @NewNode [xml]', @Data = @Data OUTPUT, @NewNode = @NewNode;

                SET @Operation = 'Insert';
            END;
        ELSE 
            BEGIN

                SET @Get_Nodes_Values_Cmd = N'SELECT @LastNodeValue  = @Data.value(''(Incumbent[1]/Data[1]/' + @ColumnName + '[1]/Value[last()])'',''[nvarchar](1024)''); 
                                                SELECT @IsTheSameValue = (CASE WHEN @LastNodeValue = @XmlValue.value(''.'',''[nvarchar](1024)'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END); ';

                EXECUTE sp_executesql @Get_Nodes_Values_Cmd, N'@Data [xml], @LastNodeValue [nvarchar](1024) OUTPUT, @IsTheSameValue [bit] OUTPUT, @XmlValue [xml]',
                 @Data = @Data, @LastNodeValue = @LastNodeValue OUTPUT, @IsTheSameValue = @IsTheSameValue OUTPUT, @XmlValue = @XmlValue     

                IF(@IsTheSameValue = 0)
                    BEGIN

                        SET @NewNode = N'<Value Date="' + CONVERT([nvarchar](64),GETDATE(),20) + N'">' + CAST(@XmlValue AS [nvarchar](1024)) + N'</Value>';                                                     

                        SET @New_Nodes_Cmd = N'SET @Data.modify(''insert sql:variable("@NewNode") as last into (/Incumbent/Data/' + @ColumnName + N')[1]'')';                       

                        EXECUTE sp_executesql @New_Nodes_Cmd, N'@Data [xml] OUTPUT, @NewNode [xml]', @Data = @Data OUTPUT, @NewNode = @NewNode;

                        SET @Operation = 'Update';

                    END;                        
            END;
```

The problem is the server memory upping 1,5gb after only one execution in the server with 15gb total.

Does anyone know what could be occurring ?

Comment: Is this memory usage causing issues? Was the table previously queried (and therefore already cached in memory)? SQL Server has to put data pages in memory to use them and it won't flush them out unless that memory is needed for something else. In short: this is probably exactly what should happen.

Comment: 1/8 isn't really a volume we can really help with. 1/8 of what? 100MB (thus 12.5 MB); not a lot then so nothing to be worried about. 80GB (thus 10GB); well then, yes this is a big jump, but then, does it matter? Like @alroc says, your SQL Server will use as much memory as it is limited to, and won't release any unless the service is restarted. If it's now using 90GB (from 80GB) so what if it's allowed to use up to 128GB? It'll (likely) use it eventually. We need more information here.

Comment: I put the piece of code that cause this issue. Am I doing something wrong ? Put your minds that when I run this code 2500 times over cursor the server memory up 1,5gb.

Comment: 1.5GB isn't that much memory unless you're running in an environment that's exceedingly constrained. Again, why is this causing a problem for you? If you run it twice, does memory go up by 3GB? SQL Server **must** consume memory to operate on data, so this is expected behavior.

Comment: It's a problem for me because the server has 15gb total memory, with more five execution it say me warning. The code is simple although I do it many times for execution.

Comment: There are much more hard code in my application, but this manipulation of xml broken all that I did until today. I can't believe that only this piece of code can do the memory to up 1,5gb by execution.

Comment: 15GB total memory = "exceedingly constrained". Memory is really cheap and SQL Server supports lots of it - 64GB in Standard Edition (128 in Standard Edition 2014+). Or perhaps you shouldn't be doing this processing in SQL at all, but rather an outside process.

Comment: Yes, I think at to do outside from database. Maybe will be the best way. Ok, thank you everyone for your helps.

Comment: I have to agree that 16GB for the whole server isn't a lot of Memory. Not sure what version of SQL Server you're using but if it's 2012 or alter I'd never consider less than 64GB, and that would be if i'm only hosting the data engine on it. if you're server is complaining that it doesn't have enough Memory, then it doesn't, or you need to limit the amount that SQL Server is using (but the lower you make it, the more it'll impact performance).

Comment: It might be possible to solve your issue entirely differently.Set up a test scenario with the needed DDL-code. Add sample data with (reduced) examples of your XM (some comprehensive combinations). And state the expected output. I'm quite sure, that there is a better way...